# Running one code with variables for 2 divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

Trying to run the same function for 2 separate divs. It should apply the class 'header-hide'/'header-show' when the user scrolls a certain distance (offset).

The working code for one div/element (no variables) is

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){


// adjust this number to select when your button appears on scroll-down
var offset = 75,

// bind with the button link
$animation = $('header');

// apply animation
$(window).scroll(function(){
    ( $(this).scrollTop() > offset ) ? $animation.addClass('header-hide').removeClass("header-show"):
    $animation.addClass('header-show').removeClass("header-hide");
});

});
```

But when I try to apply it to 2 divs using variables, doesn't work

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {

      function reusuableAnimationFunc(elementName, offset, hideClass, showClass) {
        $animation = $(elementName);

        $(window).scroll(function() {
          ($(this).scrollTop() > offset) ? $animation.addClass(hideClass).removeClass(showClass):
            $animation.addClass(showClass).removeClass(hideClass);
        });
      });

    reusuableAnimationFunc('header', 70, 'header-hide', 'header-show') 
    reusuableAnimationFunc('#top-btn', 300, 'element-hide', 'element-show')
```

```css
.element-hide,
.header-hide {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.element-show,
.header-show {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<header class="jumbotron header-show">

  <div id="jumbo-wrap">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <h1>Sub-title</h1>
  </div>

</header>

<div id="top-btn" class="element-show">
  <a href="#"> ... </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML so we can actually debug?

Comment: sure thing, wasn't sure it was nessesary

Comment: I am having trouble getting your code to execute.  Can you fix your MVCE?

Comment: I can post the working original it was derived from, but I can't get this code to work, hence the question

Comment: Also and that is more of performance tip, use only one scroll function on the parent to check for scrolling and check for its position better to do only one check instead of two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error in javascript function. You are closing reusuableAnimationFunc function with `});`, it should be `}`. Also, you need to close `document.ready()` function at the end. That function is never closed.

```
$(document).ready(function($) {    
          function reusuableAnimationFunc(elementName, offset, hideClass, showClass) {
            $(window).scroll(function() {
            $animation = $(elementName);                
              ($(this).scrollTop() > offset) ? $animation.removeClass(showClass).addClass(hideClass):
                $animation.addClass(showClass).removeClass(hideClass);
            });
          }    
        reusuableAnimationFunc('header', 70, 'header-hide', 'header-show');
        reusuableAnimationFunc('#top-btn', 300, 'element-hide', 'element-show');
        });
```

P.S move `$animation = $(elementName);` inside windows.scroll function

Comment: Oh ok, I was under the impression it was to be outside the function. But you are correct